# How to extend existing 'access comments' permission?

Tags: 8, comments

I am trying to extend access to comments based on the entity they are attached to.

I have created permissions in my permissions.yml file as following.

```
view user comments:
  title: 'View comments attached to Users'
```

Then in my `.module` file, in a `hook_entity_type_build()` I have changed the Handler Class for the Comment entity with my custom one.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_build().
 */
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  // I need this so I can alter the Comment Permisions with my custom ones.
  if (isset($entity_types['comment'])) {
    $entity_types['comment']->setHandlerClass('access', '\Drupal\MY_CUSTOM_MODULE\Access\CustomCommentAccessControlHandler');
  }
}
```

My custom class extends the initial Handler and I am only overwriting what I need.

```
/**
 * Adds a custom access handler for Comments.
 */
class CustomCommentAccessControlHandler extends CommentAccessControlHandler {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function checkAccess(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
```

`DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `CREATE/REPLY` work exactly how I wish and how I've overwritten them but my issue is with `VIEW`.

I have defined my `view` case in a switch in the `checkAccess` function like this (please note that the other cases in my switch behave as desired):

```
case 'view':
  // View comments depending on the parent entity.
  $canViewUserCom = $account->hasPermission('view user comments');
  // If parent entity is user.
  if ($entityType == 'user') {
    $access = AccessResult::allowedIf($canViewUserCom)
      ->cachePerPermissions()
      ->addCacheableDependency($entity);
    // Set reason when forbidden or neutral.
    if (!$access->isAllowed()) {
      $access->setReason("The 'view user comments' permission is required.");
    }
  }
```

I have debugged the `$access` variable and it returns what it needs to. I have tried to forbid access completely just to debug and it does not seem to overwrite the 'access comments' permission not matter what I do.

I have debugged further and I got to this class in the comment module.

```
namespace Drupal\comment;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Defines a item list class for comment fields.
 */
class CommentFieldItemList extends FieldItemList {
```

Inside this class, there is a function called `access()` which looks like this:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($operation = 'view', AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    if ($operation === 'edit') {
      // Only users with administer comments permission can edit the comment
      // status field.
      $result = AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account ?: \Drupal::currentUser(), 'administer comments');
      return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
    }
    if ($operation === 'view') {
      // Only users with "post comments" or "access comments" permission can
      // view the field value. The formatter,
      // Drupal\comment\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\CommentDefaultFormatter,
      // takes care of showing the thread and form based on individual
      // permissions, so if a user only has ‘post comments’ access, only the
      // form will be shown and not the comments.
      $result = AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account ?: \Drupal::currentUser(), 'access comments')
        ->orIf(AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account ?: \Drupal::currentUser(), 'post comments'));
        // $result = AccessResult::forbidden(); // -> I HAVE ADDED THIS TO TEST
      return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
    }
    return parent::access($operation, $account, $return_as_object);
  }
```

If I remove/overwrite line 59/60 (or in this case, I overwrite the return of the function with another access opinion), I get my desired functionality. Now, the problem is that it is not ok to edit code inside core as it will be lost with every update. How do I hook into this class in order to rewrite the `access` function? Or, is there perhaps another approach for the functionality I need (view comments based on which entity they are attached to)?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2879087 Also, this is a related issue if it helps.